# Windows 8 Store App: Image cropping with fixed ratio

Tags: windows, windows-8

I've encountered this solution from Microsoft for Image Cropping on Windows 8 App, But what I need is to force user to crop to a specific ratio (eg. 1:1, 4:3), please suggest/or any better solution is available?

Thank you very much in advance.

Here's the solution (the solution allows user to crop freely on x,y)
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSWin8AppCropBitmap-52fa1ad7/sourcecode?fileId=70609&pathId=1727496808

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSWin8AppCropBitmap-52fa1ad7

```
/// <summary> 
    /// If a pointer which is captured by the corner moves，the select region will be updated. 
    /// </summary> 
    void Corner_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 

        Windows.UI.Input.PointerPoint pt = e.GetCurrentPoint(this); 
        uint ptrId = pt.PointerId; 

        if (pointerPositionHistory.ContainsKey(ptrId) && pointerPositionHistory[ptrId].HasValue) 
        { 
            Point currentPosition = pt.Position; 
            Point previousPosition = pointerPositionHistory[ptrId].Value; 

            double xUpdate = currentPosition.X - previousPosition.X; 
            double yUpdate = currentPosition.Y - previousPosition.Y; 

            this.selectedRegion.UpdateCorner((sender as ContentControl).Tag as string, xUpdate, yUpdate); 

            pointerPositionHistory[ptrId] = currentPosition; 
        } 

        e.Handled = true; 
    }
```